# AEM Sites: Filter update fails while updating design rules using maven build

Tags: maven, aem-6

I'm are trying to set design rules in AEM 6.5 under the new content structure */apps/settings/wcm/design*. When building code, I am observing below error:

**Build Command:**  mvn -PautoInstallPackage clean install -X

```
[INFO] --- filevault-package-maven-plugin:1.0.3:generate-metadata (default-generate-metadata) @ placeholder-com.ui.apps ---
[INFO] Embedding --- Embedded: groupId=com.adobe.cq,artifactId=core.wcm.components.core,type=,classifier=,filter=false,excludeTransitive=false,target=/apps/placeholder-com/install/ ---
[INFO] Embedding com.adobe.cq:core.wcm.components.core:jar:2.7.0 (from /Users/user-name/.m2/repository/com/adobe/cq/core.wcm.components.core/2.7.0/core.wcm.components.core-2.7.0.jar) -> jcr_root/apps/placeholder-com/install/core.wcm.components.core-2.7.0.jar
[INFO] Embedding --- Embedded: groupId=com.placeholder.aem,artifactId=placeholder-com.core,type=,classifier=,filter=false,excludeTransitive=false,target=/apps/placeholder-com/install/ ---
[INFO] Embedding com.placeholder.aem:placeholder-com.core:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (from /Users/user-name/Projects/placeholder/placeholder-dot-com/aem-placeholder-site/core/target/placeholder-com.core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) -> jcr_root/apps/placeholder-com/install/placeholder-com.core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] using meta-inf/vault from /Users/user-name/Projects/placeholder/placeholder-dot-com/aem-placeholder-site/ui.apps/src/main/content/META-INF/vault
[INFO] Loading filter from /Users/user-name/Projects/placeholder/placeholder-dot-com/aem-placeholder-site/ui.apps/src/main/content/META-INF/vault/filter.xml
[INFO] Merged detected packages from analyzer with 'importPackage':
[INFO]   com.adobe.cq.sightly;version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"
[INFO]   org.apache.sling.api;version="[2.3.3,3.0.0)"
[INFO]   org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.pojo;version="[1.0.1,2.0.0)"
[INFO] 
[ERROR] 1 error(s) detected during dependency analysis.
[ERROR] Filter root's ancestor '/apps/settings/wcm/design' is not covered by any of the specified dependencies.Ï


[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.jackrabbit:filevault-package-maven-plugin:1.0.3:generate-metadata (default-generate-metadata) on project placeholder-com.ui.apps: 1 error(s) detected during dependency analysis. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.jackrabbit:filevault-package-maven-plugin:1.0.3:generate-metadata (default-generate-metadata) on project placeholder-com.ui.apps: 1 error(s) detected during dependency analysis.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 1 error(s) detected during dependency analysis.
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.filevault.maven.packaging.GenerateMetadataMojo.validateDependencies(GenerateMetadataMojo.java:617)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.filevault.maven.packaging.GenerateMetadataMojo.execute(GenerateMetadataMojo.java:428)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :placeholder-com.ui.apps
```

**Project filter.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/apps/placeholder-com"/>
    <filter root="/apps/msm/placeholder-com_blueprint" mode="merge"/>
    <filter root="/apps/settings/wcm/designs/placeholder-com"/>
</workspaceFilter>
```

FYI, I did not make any modifications to pom.xml. 
I really appreciate the help here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to our architect.

Adding the filter for the artifact **filevault-package-maven-plugin** in the pom.xml for **repository-structure** project fixed the issue.

```
<filter><root>/apps/settings/wcm/designs</root></filter>
```

Comment: Did you add this in the ui.apps pom file or in the parent pom file?

Comment: I already have <filter><root>/apps/settings</root></filter>, still do I have to add <filter><root>/apps/settings/wcm/designs</root></filter>? Could you please confirm?

Comment: Yes! You would still need to add this.